# Evaluating a limit using Taylor/Maclaurin/power series

Tags: calculus, limits

How would I evaluate this limit?  I need to use a power series approach.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left[\frac{2+x}{2x*(e^x-1)}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

First find a common denominator and combine the fractions $$\frac{2+x}{2x(e^x-1)}-\frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{x^2+2x+2-2e^x}{2x^2(e^x-1)}$$

Then Taylor expand the numerator and denominator:

$$\begin{align}x^2+2x+2-2e^x &= x^2+2x+2-2\left(1+x+\frac {x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}+\mathcal{O}(x^5)\right) \\ &= -\frac{2x^3}{3!}-\frac{2x^4}{4!}+\mathcal{O}(x^5) \\ 2x^2(-1 + e^x) &= 2x^2\left(-1 + 1+x+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\mathcal{O}(x^3)\right) \\ &= 2x^3+x^4+\mathcal{O}(x^5)\end{align}$$

So $$\frac{x^2+2x+2-2e^x}{2x^2(e^x-1)} = \frac{-\frac{2x^3}{3!}-\frac{2x^4}{4!}+\mathcal{O}(x^5)}{2x^3+x^4+\mathcal{O}(x^5)}$$

Now what do you get when you take the limit?

Comment: thanks for answering but unfortunately the (-1/x^2) isnt a part of the denominator of the first fraction, its a different fraction, but i'm not familiar with the formatting used here

Comment: Have I updated your question correctly?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot

Comment: well, after factoring out x^4 the limit would be equal to infinity, is that right?

Comment: Why are you factoring $x^4$ out?  If you do that you get $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.  Factor out $x^3$ and see what you get.

Comment: My thought process was that by factoring x^4 out, the x^4 from the numerator and the x^4 from the denominator would be simplified

Comment: But then for the $x^3$ terms you get $\frac 1x$ which approaches $\infty$ as $x\to 0$.  And $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is indeterminate.  Rule of thumb: if $x\to 0$, factor out the lowest power of $x$.  If $x\to \infty$, factor out the highest power of $x$.

Comment: Thats right, I completely forgot the highest power must be factored out only when x approaches infinity. So by factorig out x^3 the limit should be -1/6